# Expression for highlighting why studying is important

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

In my country, we have a saying that goes by "the pen is lighter than the shovel", that we use to convince kids and teenagers to overcome their laziness and take their studies seriously.

Is there a similar idiom for this, that could be said to a young person?

Comment: I rather like the sound of your proverb. It echoes an English one (which has, however' a different emphasis). The straight translation is not unknown.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess I could use a direct translation, but I'm looking for an expression that packs a bit more of the US/Commonwealth culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a quote, but with over 2.5 million Google hits, I'd say it's reached 'saying' status.

> An investment in knowledge pays the best interest.

- Benjamin Franklin

[[Selfmadesuccess.com](http://selfmadesuccess.com/investment-knowledge-pays-best-interest/)]

Answer (score 1):

> [The Pen is Mightier than the Sword.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_pen_is_mightier_than_the_sword)

or

> Work smart, not hard.

Comment: This adage is specifically about all the things being represented by 'the pen' being more effective than those represented by the sword, ie violence. How does that relate white-collar work being preferable to blue-collar as in the question?

Comment: Even thought it's not totally appropriate, I felt it was so similar to the quote in question, that the OP might want to know about us having such a similar quote. And if you consider it an argument of "intellect vs brute force", it is a little more applicable.